# Messages from HTML/JS while a PDF is open

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am a javascript noob, so this question might seem very basic and I might need a lot of directions :)
This is the effect I want to create:

The user is currently viewing a PDF in the browser. The doc is embedded with the  tag in the HTML. My PDF has forms in it, so there is some processing (validations etc) that I do inside the PDF as the user is interacting with it. Sometimes, after immediately entering a value the user closes the PDF - and my last bit of processing is incomplete.

In such a case, I would like to (1) stop the PDF from closing till my processing is done (the HTML is aware of the processing status of the PDF, so the HTML knows when a close can be allowed) (2) While I have stopped the PDF from closing, after the user has tried to close the window, I want to display some sort of a message to him indicating that the PDf is not done with the processing yet (3) When the message from (2) is being displayed to the user, interaction with the PDF should be disabled - and ideally this fact should be expressed visually. For ex, the PDF can appear grayed out in the background of the message (4)After I am done with the processing I want to close the browser window

For (1),(4) I am using onbeforeunload, and it serves my purposes well.  But on the usability front -(2), (3) - I have no clue as to how I must proceed. It could be sort of what [Google Image search does when you click on a thumbnail on the main page](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://images.free-extras.com/pics/g/garfield-1069.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.free-extras.com/cartoons.html&usg=__VpWTwwzrmSK163w4QeMTuYeqydk=&h=300&w=400&sz=48&hl=en&start=1&zoom=1&tbnid=ZDqJfdmBZVdQkM%3a&tbnh=93&tbnw=124&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dgarfield%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26biw%3D1440%26bih%3D781%26tbs%3Disch:1&um=1&itbs=1). - there is an image in the foreground(I could replace this with a message of my own), the background is grayed. However it doesnt prevent interactions with the background - clicking on it takes me to the original webpage. Also, I dont know whether the JS will work when a PDF is already open.

Thanks!

Comment: The doc is embedded with which tag?  (Escape the HTML tag using &lt;, otherwise SO will discard it).

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, squarehead's answer to his own question is to embed the PDF plugin in an HTML page while making it fill the window.

It'll look the same, but the HTML and any associated javascript will still be around and, if you're dealing with browsers which don't allow content to overlap plugins, you can just use Javascript to reduce the height of the PDF view by a couple of `em`s whenever a message needs to be displayed in order to make room for a notification bar.

Unless I'm mistaken though, `width="100%" height="100%"` isn't valid XHTML. The proper solution would be to either use `style="width: 100%; height: 100%"` or add this to the stylesheet.

```
#PDFcontent { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

---

**Update:** As for preventing the user from closing the PDF before processing is finished, the ability to do so is very restricted in order to minimize the possibility for abuse, so all you can really reliably do is display an "Are you sure?" dialog.

Here's the code I used in one of my projects:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if ($('#quote_preview').text() != "" && document.submit_warn) {
        return "The currently-entered quote has not been" +
               " submitted. Are you sure you want to discard it?";
    }
};
```

I'm using jQuery in this case, but the basic idea is that you assign a function as the `onbeforeunload` handler which determines whether an "Are you sure?" dialog needs to be displayed and, if so, returns the text to display in it.

The browser controls what extra explanation (if any) will be displayed, what the OK/Cancel buttons will look like, and whether manipulation of the page is blocked while the dialog is open. I don't think it's possible to control that last one yourself.

Comment: Looks like I bungled up sthg --- I intended to comment on Martjins Comment .... I hope the thread is still open! I still need help with (2),(3)

Comment: You should have clicked "add comment" under Martijn's comment... though it may be you need more reputation points before it will appear. I can't remember what the rules are on comments in reply to your own posts. (See the FAQ for details)

Answer (score 0):

< object id="PDFcontent" data="untitled1.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"/>